# Using jQGrid How Can I Prevent a Container from Being Disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, free-jqgrid

Using jqGrid 4.15.6-pre - free

I open an Add form to add a new row.
I one of the cells I have click dataEvent that calls the folowing:

```
function accessBudgetView(){
        
$('.rma-miscdisplay2-zoom600995').load("/QMSWebApp/RMAControllerServlet",
{lifecycle:"accessRMAMONumberRequestBudgetLayout",
nextMONumberRequestIndex:nextMONumberRequestIndex,
recseq:0}, function(){$('.rma-miscdisplay2-zoom600995').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 
1000);});
                    
}
```

This is my container code:

```
<div class="rmaMainBody"></div>
<div class="rma-miscdisplay"></div>
<div class="rma-miscdisplay2"></div>
<div class="rma-miscdisplay2-zoom600995"></div>
<div class="rma-miscdisplay3"></div>
```

My problem is the called container is disabled even though I have the z-index set higher than the addForm z-index.

Update:
CSS Code for called container:

```
.rma-miscdisplay2-zoom600995{
overflow-y: auto;
display: none;
position: absolute;
padding: 5px;
top: 100px;
bottom: 0px;
right: 2px;
background-color: silver;
color: blue;
padding: 2px;
z-index: 600995;
border-style: solid;
border-color: white;
border-width: thin; 

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

z-index only works on positioned elements. If you try to set a z-index on a non-positioned element, it will do nothing. However, there is one exception - flex children can use z-index even if they're non-positioned

Please look here: [Stacking elements - CSS z-index and stacking context explained](https://netgen.io/blog/stacking-elements-css-z-index-and-stacking-context-explained)

Please prepare a working example and publish a link to it (maybe use jsfiddle or similar), so that we can see what is happen.

Comment: I do have the called container positioned. See my update.

Comment: Can you please try with position:fixed ?

Comment: Still disabled. Everything in browser screen is disabled until I close the Add Form.

Comment: Unfortunately this is free-jqGrid and I can not help you very well. We support Guriddo jqGrid. One last try maybe is to set the modal parameter in add form to false. See if this option still exists in free-jqGrid

Comment: Where do I find out how to use the modal parameter? I do not see any reference in my web searches.

Comment: Maybe you will find a documentation for it. If nothing found you can try this [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow), but it is not for free-jqGrid

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do jqModal: false in the add form code portion as you suggested, and it worked.

Comment: I spoke too soon. With jqModal set to false my calling Add Form does not work correctly. If I change the value of an input then click in another the Add Form closes.

Comment: Is there a way to toggle the jqModal property programmatically?